# How do I move div so they don't overlap

Tags: html, css, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter on a project. I have an over lap in DIVs.

[image: div overlap block button]
<sub>(source: [childrensdaycaresoftware.com](http://childrensdaycaresoftware.com/newdaycarebuild/img/overlay.png))</sub>

In the image you can see that the overlap blocks the button. The CSS that controls this is

```
 .fam {
      position: relative;
      left: 20px;
      width: 400px;
 }
```

If I make it fixed or absolute, it throws off all the work that I have done. I would have to redo the whole page.

Is there a way to send the Family Info block behind the menu button?

The css for these two DIVs are not in the same css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to make the z-index for the button, or its container, a higher number to elevate it above the other div.

> .button{
>      z-index:5;
>   }
>   for example.